# HTML: How is favicon set at amazon dot com

Tags: html, favicon

website icons (favicons) are usually set with

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
```

but not at amazon.com, hover web browser shows its [amazon] icon, how is it made?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The majority of browsers look for `favicon.ico` in the root of the domain.

If you look at http://www.amazon.com/favicon.ico you'll see that is the case here

Comment: Thank you, it is such simple that I even didn't think about that